# Chinese Translation of these certificates (old hanja)

Tags: translation

There are a few Chinese characters on these certificates and I was wondering if someone can translate them for me please? I know the other ones are in Korean but I could not find a Korean person that could read the whole thing they could only read what's in Korean.

[image: first pics]

[image: second pic]

Comment: This is something about Korean, so please ask there if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

段證 Dan Certificate

姓名 Name 후레드 버나드 Fred Bernard

위 사람운 本道場 第三十回 審查에서 初段에 合格하였음으로 兹以 本證을 授與함.
The person above has passed the first dan during the 30th examination, and thus we award him this certificate.
1972年 6月 吉日(*) June 1, 1972

美國唐手道武德舘金道場 USA Tang Su Do Mudeokgwan Keum-Dojang
最高師範 金基璜 Chief Instructor KIM Ki-Hwang

The second is mostly illegible, but it confers a 5th dan, commenting on hard work done by the student, on December 1 1982. To someone whose name is Albert ---S or ---TH.

--

(*) 吉日 means the first day of the (lunar) month.

Comment: Ah so that's what character was... 吉日...

Answer (score 0):

Note: Korean is not my native language.

A transcription in hangeul first:

> 단증
>
> 성명: ******
>
> 위 사람은 본 도장 제"삼십"회 심사에서 초 단에 합격하였음으로 자이 본증을 수여함
>
> 1972년 6월 ?일
>
> 미국 당수도 무덕관 김도장
>
> 최고 사범 김기황

Roughly translated, this reads:

> (Class?) Certificate
>
> Name: ****************
>
> This certifies that the above person was awarded a pass of first dan by examination at this dojang (dojo) in the [30]th class.
>
> June (?), 1972
>
> US Tang Soo Do School of Martial Virtue Kim-dojang
>
> Chief Instructor Kim Ki-hwang

Comment: I **think** 金 is pronounced *geum* in this case.